# Resolving 'The process engine you are trying to access does not exist'

Tags: java, spring, process, bpmn, camunda

i'm running embedded camunda engine in my application. Now i would like to run second camunda engine with cockpit on different container with the same database. What i did is basically copy-paste of my main applciation configuration only switched dependency from `camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter` to `camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp`. I can acess cockpits main page but i'm immediately prompted `The process engine you are trying to access does not exist` and i don't understand why? On startup i can see that my`SpringProcessEngineConfiguration` bean is created as well as `ProcessEngineFactoryBean` bean. 
However:

```
BpmPlatform.getProcessEngineService().getProcessEngineNames();
```

returns empty set. 
Could you please have a look and point my mistake?

main app class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CamundaCockpitApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CamundaCockpitApplication.class, args);
    BpmPlatform.getProcessEngineService().getProcessEngineNames();
}
```

Camunda confing:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EngineConfiguration {

private final DataSource dataSource;

private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

private final ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver;

@Bean
public SpringProcessEngineConfiguration springProcessEngineConfiguration() {
    SpringProcessEngineConfiguration springConfiguration = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();
    springConfiguration.setDataSource(dataSource);
    springConfiguration.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    springConfiguration.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate("false");
    springConfiguration.setJobExecutorActivate(false);
    springConfiguration.setHistory("full");
    springConfiguration.setJdbcBatchProcessing(false);
    return springConfiguration;
}

@Bean
public ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean() {
    ProcessEngineFactoryBean engine = new ProcessEngineFactoryBean();
    engine.setProcessEngineConfiguration(springProcessEngineConfiguration());
    return engine;
}
}
```

Comment: Try adding `@EnableProcessApplication` to your main class. The webapp package is probably configured not to start the engine by default.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj you are correct, this solved my issue, if you post it as answer i will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `@EnableProcessApplication` annotation to your main class.

see https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/process-applications/